# On Mobile Login : Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: facebook, authentication

I always get this error when I try to login in my application, which uses facebook login on my phone, however my app links perfectly fine on my computer, just not on my phone.

I believe it may have something to do with the facebook login being a new pop-up page on computers, whereas on mobile its loaded as a page.

I have tried everything and the errors will alternate between:

Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

and

URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs. (which I able to login but the app fails to go to my main page which then gives this error)

depending on whether I leave the "Valid OAuth ReDIRECT Urls" section blank.(till this point I have tried all posisble redirect urls I can think of, but its no use) I have also enabled client and web oauth login and login from devices.

The Url error is of no help, which is just the error:

https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net%2F%3Fcode%3DAQBuiSRMjQ3Cpsy4SClqCyzTU9ReSvOTynI67PNIBAI0kmj1qLDb5poUzVEZSlPtUjnQ_TpXTvS7yggVJpnZiVuP6tcp4kyD3EYfjc-_5g9bSNBdUDnjixB4AufqfbYiQD6pHlRR3qhkDoOXrL56WfP7WlA0a_OZ4Me8BqfrmDd6tLuqIezi4IE-88QljOdDtekKed9z-AQuakSKty1Zu8ER91Ie3iCLBG8Fd7CczXFJkJm6aLB29QjWTC3HTPWIsknNSl_O93urR8ChochH2ANuN2hYLUD8SH6SDVYS0q4oN3_OLqqdToYwWWoZwzjop0OcWq6xiDzb5_CXnapPsP78%26state%3Dfacebookdirect%23_%3D_&state=facebookdirect&return_scopes=false&scope=public_profile%2Cemail&response_type=code&auth_type

Comment: If you are getting this error _after_ the login dialog, when Facebook has redirected back to your app already, then that usually means you supplied a different redirect_uri value in the API call that tries to exchange the code for a token, than you did in the login dialog call. These must absolutely match.

Comment: thanks for the response, but i used npm react-facebook-login package so i didn't directly call the API myself.

Comment: Such libraries often try to figure out the correct URLs to use automatically, but they can get it wrong sometimes. If the documentation has no hints on how to configure this or how it creates the URLs at least, then you‘ll probably have to inspect the code a little closer to try and find out what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. I figured it out turns out it was just one line of code that I needed. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction:)